# Does the generic list method Clear() use the method RemoveAt()?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am writing a facade for `IList<T>` to implement change tracking. Does `Clear` use `RemoveAt` or `Remove` or something else entirely? I need to know if I need to set all the items tracking state inside of `Clear` or if changing the tracking state only in `Remove`, and `RemoveAt` will be enough.

Similarly, does `Add` use `Insert`? Does `Remove` or `RemoveAt` use each other?

Any other input into such an implementation is also welcome.

Edit: Do extension methods for List use pre-existing methods or is it new code? I don't know if I need to implement those as well.

Answer (score 6):

> Does `Clear` use `RemoveAt` or `Remove` or something else entirely?

You can not rely on implementations of `IList.Clear` to use `IList.RemoveAt` or `IList.Remove`. It is up to the specific implementation to do whatever it wants.

Note that you can't even really rely on `Clear` actually removing all items from the instance. An interface does not enforce behavior, it is not actually a contract.

There's a huge misconception on what interfaces actually are. You'll hear people say that "interfaces are contracts". They are not. They merely specify that there will be some methods with certain signatures and return types that you will be able to invoke if you have an object that implements a given interface. That's it. **There is no guarantee whatsoever on the implementation, or the behavior.**

Additionally, relying on implementation details is a gigantic code smell. They could change on you at any moment without you knowing causing your code to fail and die miserably. **Do not rely on implementation details.**

> Similarly, does Add use Insert?

Similarly, you can not rely on `IList.Add` using `IList.Insert`.

> Does `Remove` or `RemoveAt` use each other?

You can not rely on it being true.

Comment: I knew this already deep down. I just didn't want to. Thanks.

Comment: An interface *is* a contract. There's no guarantee that an implementor of an interface will uphold the contract, though.

Comment: @Gabe: An interface is emphatically not a contract. Contracts are about semantics, and interfaces do not enforce semantics.

Comment: I would love to know why this was downvoted. If it was downvoted because you actually think that interfaces *are* contracts, you are wrong. I refer you to: [interfaces are not contracts](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=interfaces+are+not+contracts)

Comment: Of course interfaces have a contract. `Clear` is documented as "Removes all items from the ICollection<T>". While the runtime/compiler does not enforce this contract, it is still a contract. And unless your code is security critical and the implementer of the interface untrusted it is perfectly fine to rely on the documented contract of an interface. The documentation of an interface constitutes a contract.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: It is not a contract if its implementors are not bound to it by some sort of mechanism. Since the semantics are not guaranteed, it is not a contract.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that a contract needs to be enforced to be a contract. And I understand Cwalina's post is that just because you created created an interface in your code you have no useful contract, so you need to specify the contract through other means, such as documentation or code-contracts. And since there is documentation for `IList<T>` that specifies its contract, every conforming implementation needs to behave like specified.

Comment: @Jason: Perhaps you are using a different definition of the word "contract" than the rest of us. To me, a contract is an agreement -- a document containing terms and conditions that both sides agree on. It could be that the document says "By claiming you implement `IList<T>` you agree that invoking the `Clear` method will remove all items from the container" or it could say "By accepting this house, you agree to give me $1000000". In neither case can you assume that both ends of the agreement will be upheld!

Comment: @Gabe: You're missing a key point about the everyday use of the word "contract" that you refer to in your analogy. Namely: contracts are legally enforceable. It is exactly because the parties in a contract are legally bound to some obligations and that there is a mechanism in place for enforcing those obligations or receiving remedies for breach of contract that make contracts useful devices in our world. There is no mechanism whatsoever for enforcing or remedying a breach to withhold the statements in the documentation for `IList.Clear`. Your analogy is flawed.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: There is no such thing as contract through documentation. It can not be enforced, so it's not a contract.

Comment: Most people would think the *contract* is exactly what you point out, *that a given method or property exists*. That is certainly what is enforced. Naturally, *what it does* and *the implementation details thereof* cannot be assumed. It could very well do nothing or even throw an exception, such as the array implementation of `IList<T>.Add`.

Comment: I never talked about contracts in law. I'm talking about contracts in programming. There most contracts take the form of documentation. You can rely on what's documented, you can't rely on what the current version of the implementation does unless it's documented. Everything I've read on blogs of developers I respect seems to agree with that view, in particular oldnewthing, Larry Osteman's blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2007/01/12/software-contracts-part-3-documentation.aspx ... Can you cite a reputable source that states that documentation doesn't constitute a contract?

Comment: You guys are talking past each other. There is a difference between what parts of a contract an interface *enforces* by way of the type system, and what parts of a contract an interface merely *represents* by way of convention. IDisposable *enforces* that disposable objects have a void-returning method called Dispose. IDisposable *represents* the contract "you're going to call this method exactly once as soon as possible when you're done with this object".

Comment: A quick look at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contract shows that the first definition of "contract" is "an agreement between two or more parties for the doing or not doing of something specified." This is the definition I meant. However even the next definition "an agreement enforceable by law" doesn't mean that you can rely on another party to actually do what they're contractually bound to -- it just means that you have legal recourse if they don't.

Comment: @Gabe: When I implement `IList`, I didn't make an agreement with anyone to have it be the case that `IList.Clear` removes all the items from the collection.

Comment: @Anthony I actually dislike that `IList` encompasses as much functionality as it does (and that `Array` nevertheless implements it.) Ideally, there would be something like `IIndexable` that provides access by index (which `Array` would support.) `IList` could then inherit from `IIndexable`, and add on the ability to Add/Remove/Insert/etc.

Regardless, your point that interfaces guarantee functions with signatures and not behaviour is well-taken.

Comment: @Jason: Heck, you didn't make an agreement that your class is a collection at all. As Eric points out, there are syntactic guarantees (which must be met) and semantic guarantees (which I think *should* be met, but clearly may not be.)

Comment: @dlev: Look, I get Eric's point. But realize that I'm responding exactly to a claim about the documentation that `IList.Clear` removes all the item is a contract on `IList`. In this case, I am not talking past the persons making and defending those claims.

Comment: @Jason I agree; I was merely trying to support your point about not having made any agreements to supply particular functionality by virtue of implementing an interface.

Comment: @dlev: I misread your comment. I'm sorry. I agree with you, obviously. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if you write a facade since these methods are not virtual. Event if implementation of Clear called Remove (it doesn't) it wouldn't be your overriden Remove.

So that makes your life easier. You are free to implement this tracking fully in your wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

`IList` is simply a contract. What a class implementing `IList` does behind the scenes is its own business and it doesn't have to make any promises. Some implementors might iterate through their items and call `Remove` against them, while others might just delete their backing store and create a new one, or many other possibilities.

It's probably not a good idea to assume someone implementing an interface implements it in a certain way. This is certain to break in unexpected ways at some point.

Answer (score 2):

From source, `List<T>` uses [Array.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx)

```
// Clears the contents of List.
public void Clear() { 
    if (_size > 0) 
    {
        Array.Clear(_items, 0, _size); // Don't need to doc this but we clear the elements so that the gc can reclaim the references. 
        _size = 0;
    }
    _version++;
}
```

Comment: @OpticalDelusion, you can use tools like Reflector or check out this blog post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx